# Will a 30"x80" prehung door fit in a 31" x 82" rough opening?

Tags: doors, interior

I have a number of doors I need to install. My rough openings range from 31" wide up to 32" wide. Will a 30"x80" prehung door fit in these openings? Or do I need to trim out the door frame and buy a door slab?

Comment: What does "trim out the door frame" mean?

Comment: A better question might be about modifying the smaller openings to fit a standard door. That may very well be the path of least resistance. We'd need more information, though.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check on a per-opening and per-door basis. Actual exterior size for 30 inch pre-hung doors including the frame is often 31.5 to 32 inches. So for the 32 inch roughs, you can almost certainly use pre-hung doors. For anything closer to 31 inches it will probably be touch and go, or may be impossible.

Comment: I'd have stated it a little less doubtfully--unless the jamb is 1/2" thick or thinner, and unless the opening is perfectly square, it won't fit in a 31" opening. Period.

Comment: Fair point - I also wanted to give the asker the benefit of the doubt that maybe 31" means 31+something and 32" means 32+something. Either way it's time to break out the tape measure.